# Having an independent scrollable Table of Contents pane for a webpage

Tags: html, css, markdown, pandoc

Currently I have a webpage which looks like this

[image]

I expect the table of contents to grow quite a bit. Hence I would like to have a separate window pane on the left hand-side of the page that is independently scrollable and collapsible (sort of like https://docs.python.org/3/). Can this be specified from within a CSS stylesheet? I typically use pandoc and markdown together with a customized css stylesheet to layout my webpage.

Also how can I have a separate webpage (say the homepage of my website) containing only the table of contents with a list of links to the actual articles, for instance as on Noam Chomsky's [website](https://chomsky.info/articles/). Again a solution with pandoc and markdown is preferred.

Comment: to have multiple output pages you need something more than only pandoc, see https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Pandoc-Extras#static-website-generators For hosting, https://pages.github.com is a great start..

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following CSS:

```css
#TOC {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
body {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```